# How to get the value inside a repeaters itemtemplate?

Tags: asp.net, repeater

```
<asp:Repeater ..>
<ItemTemplate>
<% string age = Eval("a").ToString() %>

<%
   age = a.ToLower(); // real stuff here
%>

<p>Hello <%# Eval("name") %> you are <%= age %> old</p>

</ItemTemplate>    
</asp:Repeater>
```

I'm getting an error saying:

```
Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `<%# Eval("<propertyName>") %>`

Of course you will have to assign a `DataSource` to your repeater, and call `DataBind()`

And, without using those inline coding, you can wrap the whole logic to a custom property for your data item. For example, as in the above code, you can create a custom property say, `Age` like:

```
partial class YourDataItemClass // use partial if it is auto-generated
{
    public string Age
    {
        var ageStr = a.ToString(); // assuming YourDataItemClass  has an `a` var/property
        // Do real stuff here
        ...
        ...
        var lowered = ageStr.ToLower();
        ...
        ...
        return lowered;
    }
}
```

and you can expose that property inside the repeater control like:

```
<asp:Repeater id="myRepeater" ..>
<ItemTemplate>
    <p>Hello <%# Eval("Name") %> you are <%# Eval("Age") %> old</p>
</ItemTemplate>    
</asp:Repeater>
```

Assign datasource and databind the repeater somewhere in the code-behind like:

```
...
// Call the method which provides you the data
// IEnumerable<YourDataItemClass> myData = ... ; 
myRepeater.DataSource = myData;
myRepeater.DataBind();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Repeater>
<ItemTemplate>
 <p>Hello <%# Eval("name") %> you are <%# Convert.ToString(Eval("a")).ToLower()  %>   old</p>

</ItemTemplate>    
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: I want to assign a variable that value from Eval("a")

Comment: then put data in label and in RowDatabound, get value from label.